# Confluent Cloud - Can't see significant multithreading improvements in poll()

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I tried consuming messages from Confluent Cloud cluster using 2 approaches and I'm getting almost the same total poll() time for both-

1. Single threaded- Use only one consumer to sequentially read from all TopicPartitions
2. Multithreaded- Spawn multiple Consumers (equal to no. of TopicPartitions), assign each partition on separate consumer manually (using #assign()). Run these threads in parallel and do a #poll(). Processing of messages will also be done by the thread itself.

There is some speed increase in 2nd approach but it's mostly due to the processing part which happens in parallel. The time taken by poll() method (to fetch all ConsumerRecords, excluding the processing) is almost same in both cases.

My question- Is the poll() method in KafkaConsumer blocking on the server side in some way? Multiple consumers polling in parallel vs a single consumer polling sequentially is giving almost similar poll time. The only performance increase seems to be happening due to the processing part which happens after fetching all ConsumerRecords using poll().

NOTE: I am not using the consumer group functionality here as it is not suitable to our use-case. As mentioned, I'm manually assigning the TopicPartitions.

Comment: Can you pose a link to your testing code? This sounds very weird and I'd be happy to take a look. If you want to try out another approach to concurrent processing - try out Confluent's Parallel Consumer - it will further subdivide the work for large performance gains. https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

Answer (score 0):

What could be advised when trying to do multi threading or parallel consumers are these two blogs - [Confluent Cloud - Can't see significant multithreading improvements in poll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267848/confluent-cloud-cant-see-significant-multithreading-improvements-in-poll) and  https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-consumer-multi-threaded-messaging/. I was informed that the main point of running multiple concurrent consumers in a group is generally not about improving the performance of the fetch from Kafka, but improving processing throughput.